# How to use CSS to blur video edges overlayed on top of an image?

Tags: html, css, frontend, web-frontend

I currently have a video overlaid on top of an image. I want to blur the borders of the video such that it softly blends into the underlying image below. Is there a way for me to do this with HTML/CSS?

Here's the JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/blahblahtest/d8at3q5h/

```css
#container {
  margin-left: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

#background_image,
#overlaid_video {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

#overlaid_video {
  z-index: 10;
  margin-top: 65px;
  margin-left: 152px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="background_image">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ee/a4/6b/eea46b9905896b7336f6ca60e238ff67.jpg" height="820px">
  </div>
  <div id="overlaid_video">
    <video id="video" width="256" autoplay muted>
      <source src="https://media.gettyimages.com/videos/reptile-video-id473277749" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can used `box-shadow` to blur the border of image.

```
#video {
  box-shadow: green 0px 0px 25px 10px;
}
```

Comment: This adds a shadow, it doesn't blur the video.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of brutal way but better than nothing i guess. Also im quite sure yoo could do the same using  [clip-path](https://css-tricks.com/blurred-borders-in-css/) and it could greatly reduce css code.

Adjust width, height and position to your needs

```
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="background_image">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ee/a4/6b/eea46b9905896b7336f6ca60e238ff67.jpg" height="820px">
  </div>
  <div id="overlaid_video">
    <div class="container">
      <video id="video" width="256" autoplay muted>
        <source src="https://media.gettyimages.com/videos/reptile-video-id473277749" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>

#container {
    margin-left: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

#background_image,
#overlaid_video {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

#overlaid_video {
  z-index: 10;
  margin-top: 65px;
  margin-left: 152px;
}


#overlaid_video:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 5%;
  height: 95%;
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}

.container:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 5%;
  height: 95%;
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}

#overlaid_video:after {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 2%;
  width: 96%;
  height: 5%;
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}

.container:after {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 3%;
  left: 2%;
  width: 96%;
  height: 5%;
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}
```